# JRException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I am trying to generate a report using Jasper Reports, but I am getting the following error.

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

I am using this Java code:

```
    List<Aluno> lista = alunoService.findAll();
    String path = req.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF");
    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path + "/relatorios/aluno.jasper");
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, path + "/relatorios/teste.pdf");
```

The error is ocurring when try to compile report:

```
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path + "/relatorios/aluno.jasper");
```

The aluno.jrxml file is in UTF-8 enconding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I've researched this problem, but they all say that the reason is because the jrxml filw is not in UTF-8 enconding. If anyone could help me, I really thank.

**Java code using `aluno.jrxml`**

```
    List<Aluno> lista = alunoService.findAll();
    String path = req.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF");
    JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(path + "/relatorios/aluno.jrxml");
    JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista));
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, path + "/relatorios/teste.pdf"
```

Comment: `JasperCompileManager.compileReport(path + "/relatorios/aluno.jasper");` - you should compile the *jrxml* file. Try code like this: `JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("test.jrxml");`

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` at the beginning of your file doesn't mean that the file is actually stored in UTF-8 encoding, that just means "I swear this file has this encoding".

Do you have in your file characters other than the classic ASCII? (something like the Spanish N with a tilde on it?)

Try opening your file with a decent editor and save it again, choosing explicitly the encoding as UTF-8 **AND** after that have a look at your special characters inside your file to see if they are still the same.

Comment: I opened `aluno.jrxml` with Sublime and save with enconding UTF-8, but the problem still, so I guess the problem is when compile `aluno.jrxml` to `aluno.jasper`, so I generate my report using `aluno.jrxml` because I was sure that my `jrxml` was in rigth encondig.

Comment: I am gonna update my question with Java code using `jrxml` file instead of `jasper` file. I really thank you and I hope this helps other people.