# JsperReport don't show any data in JavaFx

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I create invoice design with JasperReport and I add fields manually (with same database fields name) and parameters, but when I click button to show the invoice ("which made using JasperReport") empty JasperView appear and don't show any data, even if I add No Data section massage and there data in my database to show, here my report design:

[image]

and code rendering this design here:

```
    btnShowReport.setOnMouseClicked(e ->
    {
        try
        {
            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\smartware\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects" +
                                                         "\\POSFX\\src\\View\\Reports\\BillDesign.jrxml");
            JRDesignQuery query = new JRDesignQuery();
            HashMap <String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap <> ();

            hashMap.put("BillType", stageTitle);
            hashMap.put("ProductValue", 50);

            query.setText("select ProductName, ProductUnit, Quantity, Price from " +
                          "BillDetails");

            jasperDesign.setQuery(query);

            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, hashMap,
                                                                   DatabaseConnection.
                                                                   connection);

            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
        }

        catch(JRException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    });
```

the running result here:

[image]

and the lib I used here:

[image]
[image]

help please, thanks in advance(I spent a lot of time to solve this and search but I failed)

Comment: Your report is not compiled. Your file should be .jasper not .jrxml. y are u passing connection object?

Comment: Ok I'll try now

Comment: @MorganDenis this excption appear "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.", and when I search I found it should be .jrxml, I found this answer here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825148/jrexception-invalid-byte-1-of-1-byte-utf-8-sequence"

Comment: I thought I shared with you a complete link on how to generate receipt using jasper

Comment: no links in your comment bro

Comment: I have another question, how to pass multiple values to "ProductValue" parameter and display this values in different rows with product Quantity and Price "ProductValue = Quantity * Price" how to make this?